# Update Blob Storage Keys to apps

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have created a PowerShell script to update a key vault with new blob storage key every time when the key rotates but the problem I have is how do I update the apps with the new blob storage key.

I have used Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy to give the apps access to the key vault secret which contains the latest storage key. I have a logic app which uses blob storage but when the key is rotated the blob storage within the logic app show an error. This is the error I encounter:

```
{

  "status": 403,

  "message": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\r\nclientRequestId: 7c8edbdf-e7c9-4658-8370-54102589213e",

  "source": "azureblob-uks.azconn-uks-01.p.azurewebsites.net"

}
```

Is there a way for the logic app to get the latest key from the key vault.

Answer (score 0):

Logic app does support a connector to connect your logic app to Azure KeyVault to retrieve the keys: **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/keyvault/**

My suggestion is to write a specific script which would discard the rotated keys, then retrieve the new ones as soon as they are available in Azure Key vault.

Comment: I can retrieve the latest key from Azure Key Vault via logic app but I am not sure what to do next once I retrieve the key.

Comment: one way to check if your scripts contain the latest key, is once you rotate, compare the key in your program vs what's in key vault, then replace it within your scripts if this helps